# Infimum of $\{\frac{11}{n + 3} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: inequality, supremum-and-infimum

I am proving that infimum of $\{\frac{11}{n + 3} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is indeed $0$, but I am stuck:

how to prove that $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{11}{n + 3} < \epsilon$?

Comment: You should be proving that such an $n$ exists because it is not true for all $n$. In this case use the inequality you desire then solve for $n$. Choose an $n$ that satisfies that relation then undo the calculation to prove that such an $n$ exists.

Comment: How to find such $n$?

Comment: It will depend on the $\epsilon$. Solve $11/(n+3) < \epsilon$ for $n$ then choose an $n$ big enough to make that statement true. Then reverse the steps to finish the proof.

Comment: I get $n > \frac{11}{\epsilon} - 3$. How to choose proper $n$? Obviously $\lceil \frac{12}{\epsilon} \rceil$ should work but I don't think it's a right way to do this...

Comment: That is a perfectly acceptable value for $n$. Smaller values would also work (e.g. $\lceil\frac{11}{\epsilon}\rceil$), but your $n$ does the job nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea that you describe is perfectly OK.

If you set $n=\lceil\frac{12}{\epsilon}\rceil$, then you know that $n\geq \frac{12}{\epsilon}$.

From that inequality, you can then deduce the following:

$$n > \frac{11}{\epsilon}\\
n\epsilon > 11\\
(n+3)\epsilon > 11
\epsilon > \frac{11}{n+3}$$

Note that every line above follows from the previous line, so it proves that your choice of $n$ satisfies the condition $\frac{11}{n+3}<\epsilon$.

Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, you can therefore conclude that

$$\forall \epsilon \exists n: \frac{11}{n+3}<\epsilon$$

which of course proves that $0$ is the largest possible lower bound (i.e., the infimum) of your set.

Comment: Thank you. You are from Slovenia? Well, I anticipate the match between Slovenia and Croatia at the upcoming handball Euro! :)